# only one out of three conditions(Logos) in a script works, other logos don't respond - unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made an animation where if you click one of the logos, the one that got clicked will move towards the center and the other logos will move to the sidewards [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwPoU.png), but somehow the code that I developed only works on the blue logo (Designer). The engineer(Green) and artist(Yellow) doesn't not work when I click them.

Even after the animation is finished, the other logo still did not respond.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        onCenter = true;
    }
    Movement();
}


// Functions//
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Vector3 mousePos;
    mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
}

private void Movement()
{
    if (onCenter)
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.gameObject.transform.position, center, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (this.gameObject.tag == "Artist")
        {
            Engineer.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Engineer.gameObject.transform.localPosition, Estandby, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            Designer.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Designer.gameObject.transform.localPosition, Dstandby, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (this.gameObject.tag == "Designer")
        {
            Engineer.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Engineer.gameObject.transform.localPosition, Estandby, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            Artist.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Artist.gameObject.transform.localPosition, Astandby, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (this.gameObject.tag == "Engineer")
        {
            Designer.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Designer.gameObject.transform.localPosition, Dstandby, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            Artist.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Artist.gameObject.transform.localPosition, Astandby, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(Engineer.gameObject.transform.position.x== 8.251f|| Designer.gameObject.transform.position.x == 8.251f|| Artist.gameObject.transform.position.x == 8.251f)
        {
            onCenter = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I bet you forgot to add (attach) the script to the other logos ;)

Comment: I just fixed it somehow, it was caused by the program reading all the tags at the same time causing it to have trouble